# How to get result set of Oracle pivot Stored procedure in JAVA?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, pivot

Can anyone help me for retrieving result set of Oracle pivot Stored procedure in JAVA. My Stored procedure is given below

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE TESTP 
(
  p_cursor out sys_refcursor

) AS 


    in_clause varchar2(256);
    sel_query varchar2(256);
    n number := 0;

BEGIN


 for  x in (select distinct VENDOR_ID from MF_QUOTATIONS)
    loop    
        if n <> 0 then 
                in_clause := in_clause || ', ';
        end if;
        in_clause := in_clause ||  '''' || x.VENDOR_ID || '''';
        n := 1;    
    end loop;

open p_cursor for select * from (select ITEM_ID, VENDOR_ID, TOTAL from MF_QUOTATIONS) pivot (max(TOTAL) for VENDOR_ID in ('||in_clause||'));




END TESTP;
```

When i run this at SQL developer it showing following errors

```
Connecting to the database DBPURCH.
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "DBPURCH.TESTP", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 5
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database DBPURCH.
```

I want to get the result set of the above SP in my JAVA application. Help me folks.

Comment: I'm confused.  It doesn't appear that your procedure is valid (for a number of reasons).  If the procedure isn't valid, why aren't you asking how to fix the procedure rather than how to call it from Java?

Comment: @JustinCave When i assigned the query to a variable like this - sel_query := 'select * from (select ITEM_ID, VENDOR_ID, TOTAL from MF_QUOTATIONS) pivot (max(TOTAL) for VENDOR_ID in ('||in_clause||'));';  and just print the query using dbms_output.put_line (sel_query); i got the desired query which i needed. Thats why i think the SP is correct.

Comment: The code you've posted isn't valid.  And, I assume, it's not the actual code that you're using (`in_clause` is presumably not NULL for example).  The fact that you're getting an error calling the procedure from SQL Developer strongly implies that your actual code is also invalid.  I have no idea, though, where the invalid number error is coming from, though, since your procedure doesn't seem to have a 17th line.

Comment: @JustinCave If the SP is not correct could you correct it?

Comment: Possibly.  You'd need to tell us what it's supposed to do.  And where things like `in_clause` are coming from.  I'm assuming that your goal isn't to pivot based on a NULL column set.

Comment: 17th line is the line where SQL query is assigned to p_cursor

Comment: If i am print the Query using  dbms_output.put_line () i will get the query as select * from (select ITEM_ID, VENDOR_ID, TOTAL from MF_QUOTATIONS) pivot (max(TOTAL) for VENDOR_ID in ('22', '24', '23'));

Comment: Possibly, you want to treat the entire query as a string that you dynamically assemble and then use that in the `OPEN` statement.  Possibly, that is why the `sel_query` variable exists (but is not used) in the code that you posted.  Again, though, looking at code that obviously differs from what you're actually using, it's hard to know what errors are real and what errors are transcription errors.  I'm still not sure how you'd get an invalid number error here but I'm making a lot of guesses about what values your variables might actually have.

Comment: @JustinCave i have forget to write some code between my SP i am sorry. Now check i have updated the SP

Comment: @JustinCave I found that invalid number exception is comes with '||in_clause||'